# $(\sec^2 10^\circ+\tan10^\circ)(\sec^2 50^\circ-\tan50^\circ)(\sec^2 70^\circ+\tan70^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

> Calculate:
>   $$(\sec^210^\circ+\tan10^\circ)(\sec^250^\circ-\tan50^\circ)(\sec^270^\circ+\tan70^\circ)$$

I tried converting them into sine and cosine, but proved of no use.

The one notorious combination I saw is let $Φ=10^\circ$ then $\tan 50^\circ = \tan (60^\circ-Φ)$ and $\tan 70^\circ= \tan (60+Φ)^\circ$ and $\tan 10^\circ= \tan Φ^\circ $, but could not proceed further.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your math text. This link may be a useful reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint.

Show that $\tan10^{\circ}$,  $\tan70^{\circ}$ and  $\tan130^{\circ}$ are roots of the following equation.
$$x^3-\sqrt3x^2-3x+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}=0$$

I got $\frac{52-\sqrt3}{3}$.